# ConnectionNotFoundException occur when open https connection in CerEm J.V.M

Tags: ssl, https, java-me

I have a web site "some.website.com" that is listening to port 80(http) and port 443(https). When I execute following code in CrE-ME™ v4.12 jvm:

```
HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://www.example.com/");
```

My Program works correctly without any issue. When I execute following code in CrE-ME™ v4.12 jvm:

```
HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("https://www.example.com/");
```

I am getting ConnectionNotFoundException : The requested protocol does not exist

When I execute following code in Java Web Start:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

or

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com/");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

I don't get any problem.

Please help me to solve this https issue in CrE-ME™ v4.12 jvm.

Comment: I have no experience with https, so someone will most likely give a better answer soon. Until then; I'm guessing that JavaME doesn't automatically install the certificate needed for the https connection. Try going to https://simple-soft.info with the phone browser first to install the certificate (or in some other way make sure that the certificate is installed on the phone), and then try again.

Comment: The device that install CrE-ME™ v4.12 jvm is Windows Mobile, and I tried to access the website via Internet Explorer in the device. The IE is able to load https content.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. I'd guess that it's a limitation in CrE-ME then. While waiting for other replies, you could try out another JavaME JVM. Personally I like http://davy.preuveneers.be/phoneme/?q=node/10 a lot, as I've had great results on Android and an older Windows Mobile device. Have never tried opening a https connection though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this problem is very simple. Use URL to open connection instead of Connector. Same coding as Java Web Start.

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com/");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```